# Something is changing my css

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I have this page where I'm using Bootstrap, Jquery and Angular js.
Today for no reason I saw that there was something that it was changing the size of the whole page.

Using Dev-tool I discover a style tag that if removed everything retrun on the normal size. (the website is responsive)

using the break on subtree modifications on the head of the page I found this:

[image]

Here the page cover the whole size of the browser then this function is called from jquery.js:

```
function() {
    return this.domManip( arguments, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
            var target = manipulationTarget( this, elem );
            target.insertBefore( elem, target.firstChild );
        }
    });
```

and the tag appears inside the head:

[image]

Could you help me to understand why this is happening?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: I used ng-cloak but I have always the same issue, this ng-cloak should disappear when everything is done but is still there.
I'm using some request with http of angular to reterive some json but at the begining was working fine why not now?